# Pechkin HTML to PDF that image is not sowing in pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am woring in Asp.net(C#) .i am trying convert html to PDF using Pechkin, PDF convert successfully.., but in my html  tag is their that image is not showing in PDF,please Help Me

My html code is

```
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_img_header" 
    src="/CompanyLogos/12_09_YYYY_07_41_48_logo.png" style="width:130px"
```

and my .cs page Code IS

```
byte[] pdfContent = new SynchronizedPechkin(
    new GlobalConfig())
        .Convert(
            new ObjectConfig()
                .SetLoadImages(true)
                .SetPrintBackground(true)
                .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                .SetAllowLocalContent(true), 
            html);

  Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(pdfContent), filename.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your image, you'll need to convert it to base64, VERY rough example

```
var base64 = convertTobase64(myImg);

<img src=base64 />
```

An example of the converting an image to base64 in Asp.NET can be found [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2028719.aspx?Convert%20Image%20to%20Base64). After converting the image to a base64 string, set the source of your image to the base64 string instead of the image URL. Then your image will appear in your PDF.

If you wanna accomplish this in javascript/html it's pretty easy.

```
<canvas id='imgCanvas' style='display:none;'></canvas>

var dataUrl;
var myImg = new Image();
var canvas = document.getElementById('imgCanvas');

$(myImg).on('load', function(){
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    dataUrl = canvas.toDataUrl('png');
});

img.src = '/CompanyLogos/12_09_YYYY_07_41_48_logo.png'
```

And then you just set the source of your image tag to the dataUrl variable and it will render in your PDF.

Comment: but my image is fetching through jquery

Comment: jquery code like  $('#<%=img_header.ClientID%>').attr('src', '/CompanyLogos/' + data.d[i].Company_logo);

Comment: I edited my answer to include some javascript code that should work for you